# Type error: unpacking tuples Recursive function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return

I have the following piece of code:

```
def myCalculation(self, root, max_val): 
        
        if root == None:
            return -1
        
        LH = 1 + (self.myCalculation(root.left, max_val))[0]
        RH = 1 + (self.myCalculation(root.right, max_val))[0]
        
        ret = LH+RH
        
        if max_val < ret:
            max_val = ret
            
        return (max(LH, RH), max_val)
```

Here, I return two values because for the last function call on stack to exit the function must return the max_val to the calling function. So, when at the 3rd and 4th executable lines of the function I make a function call and try to use the return values, it gives TypeError desribed just below.

The error is :

```
> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Full traceback:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
    LH = 1 + (self.myCalculation(root.left, max_val))[0]
Line 14 in myCalculation (Solution.py)
    LH = 1 + (self.myCalculation(root.left, max_val))[0]
Line 14 in myCalculation (Solution.py)
    LH, max_val1 = 1 + self.myCalculation(root.left, 0)
Line 32 in diameterOfBinaryTree (Solution.py)
    ret = Solution().diameterOfBinaryTree(param_1)
Line 67 in _driver (Solution.py)
_driver()
```

Line 77 in  (Solution.py)

I cannot quite figure what the problem is with packing and unpacking tuples in recursion?

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: The problem is when you return a ```-1``` when ```root == None```, then your ```LH = 1 + (self.myCalculation(root.left, max_val))[0]``` would be equivalent to ```LH = 1 + (-1)[0]```  So you need to either check for -1 before assigning to LH, or you return a tuple (though not sure how that would work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your base case returns a *single* value. However, you can simplify your algorithm by removing the need to return multiple values and the extra parameter, `max_val`. We can calculate the `diameter` of a tree, `t` -

```py
def diameter(t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return max(                            # return maximum of:
      diameter(t.left),                    # diameter of left
      diameter(t.right),                   # diameter of right
      1 + height(t.left) + height(t.right) # or diameter of t itself
    )
```

Where `height` of a tree, `t`, is defined as -

```py
def height(t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return 1 + max(height(t.left), height(t.right))
```

You can write `myCalculation` in your `Solution` class -

```py
class Solution:
  def myCalculation(self, root):
    return diameter(root)
```

Because `height` will be called multiple times on child nodes, this program can be optimized using [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), effectively "memoizing" the function -

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
def height(t):
  # ...
```